# ASP .Net Core Access the DistributedRedisCache in the JWTBearerOptions.Events OnTokenValidated Event

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, redis, .net-core, jwt

I have an ASP .Net Core API Project. In this project I am using JWTBearer Authentication. I am also using the AddDistributedRedisCache feature of the .Net Core Dependency Injection. (Both shown below)

We have a need to blacklist the tokens on occasion (Admin user removing rights, logout, etc) so that these can take immediate effect. Essentially forcing a user to log back in before the next call can be made.

We are adding the JWT Tokens to the redis cache as well as removing them from the client side cache on logout. But a user could (in theory) store the JWT token, and still gain access until the token expires, unless we intercept the call and check it against the blacklist.

How can I access the distributed cache object in the "OnTokenValidated" event in the code below? Do I have to manually create a new connection each time? We are only checking valid tokens, as that will stop invalid requests from even being checked against the blacklist.

Bearer Token Config:

```
services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddJwtBearer(options =>
                {
                    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                    {
                        ValidateIssuer = true,
                        ValidateAudience = true,
                        ValidateLifetime = true,
                        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                        ValidIssuer = "localhost:5000",
                        ValidAudience = "localhost:5000",
                        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(
                            Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration.GetValue<string>("SigningKey"))),
                    };
                    options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
                        {
                            OnTokenValidated = context => {
                                //context.Fail("User has been logged out");
                                return Task.CompletedTask;
                            }
                        };
                });
```

Redis Cache Config:

```
services.AddDistributedRedisCache(option =>
            {
                option.Configuration = Configuration.GetValue<string>("RedisCacheAddress");
                option.InstanceName = Configuration.GetValue<string>("RedisCacheInstance");
            });
```

Comment: I'm exactly working on the same thing. Can you share how you validate the JWT token from Redis or any article about that?

Comment: For this instance (which was almost 4 years ago, and in my last job) I think I literally took an MD5 has of the whole jwt token (if it was blacklisted - i.e. logged out, or user disabled etc..) and then just dumped that MD5 into redis for like 24 hours, longer than the token was valid for... so when I was checking to see if a token was valid, I could do a quick md5 hash, try and get that from redis, if it was blacklisted I would get a hit and I could deny access.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'm using multiple caching mechanisms, and I'm using my own Interface. So I handle it like that var cache = ctx.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<IDistributedCacheManager>();
var cachedValue = cache.GetCacheValue<string>("MYTOKENKEY")); if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(cachedValue) || cachedValue != currentToken)
{throw new Exception.ValidationException("Invalid Token!");} Like @juunas answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access services in DI utilizing the HttpContext available there:

```
OnTokenValidated = ctx =>
{
    var cache = ctx.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<IDistributedCache>();
    return Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

`GetRequiredService` will throw an exception if the service is not found. You can use `GetService<T>()` if you want the service to be optional.

Comment: Ah this is perfect mate, I’ll try in the morning thank you!